# difference between getPath() and getPaths() google maps

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm trying to compute the area of a polygon. I don't think the results I'm getting are correct. When I drag the points of the polygon, the area doesn't change. From what the API says, getPath() "Retrieves the first path.", while getPaths() "Retrieves the paths for this polygon"

when I use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon)     {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPaths().getArray());
    console.log(coordinates);
    area=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(coordinates);
    console.log('Polygon Area is: ' + area);
});
```

I get a numerical result that I don't think is correct (sometimes, it doesn't change when I move the handles around. However, if I use:

```
var coordinates = (polygon.getPaths().getArray());
console.log(coordinates);
area=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(coordinates);
console.log('Polygon Area is: ' + area);
```

it complains that "`coords: [object Object]
localhost/:182
NEW Polygon Area is: 0`"

How do I use getPaths() correctly??

Comment: Do you have multiple paths in your polygon (holes or separate pieces)?  If not, getPath will give you the (one and only) path (as an MVCArray).

Comment: D'oh - I was thinking points, not paths :$. But the question remains - Why doesn't the area change if I move the handles around?

Comment: You didn't post enough code for me to answer that.

Comment: This is old, but I think the API has a bug where the functionality of `getPath` and `getPaths` is reversed.